# JSON_EXTRACT example not working on DBeaver mysql version 8.0.33

Tags: mysql, json, dbeaver

I'm trying to get JSON_EXTRACT to work on a Digital Ocean droplet, executing

select version();

gives me 8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04.2

And I'm trying to use the example from the documentation that says it should work
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains

but the code I pasted from the example:

```
SET @j = '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": {"d": 4}}';
SET @j2 = '1';
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@j, @j2, '$.a');
```

returns NULL

Can anyone help?

Update:
here's a screenshot of DBeaver showing the NULL
[image]

Update:
It transpired that I was at fault, I was not executing the whole script, so the Set commands were not being executed, so the Select command had nothing to work on. Thank you to DBeaver Support!

[image]

Comment: But you show a `JSON_CONTAINS()` ??

Comment: You do realise that the `JSON_CONTAINS()` returns a 1 or a 0?

Comment: Cannot reproduce [Example query)(https://dbfiddle.uk/IaanjJ4J

Comment: Sorry, I was focussing on EXTRACT but couldn't get it to work, so I tried copying an exact example from the same page which was actually CONTAINS - in fact the same issue is with both, I can't get anything apart from NULL @RiggsFolly I saw your code working, but mine still doesn't ! Update above

Comment: Hmm Odd. And what happend if you take Dbeaver out of the equation and run that from the terminal

Comment: I've run the same test in phpMyAdmin SQL editor and it runs fine, so it appears that DBeaver is the issue here, but I have no choice but to use it in this case. Have any of you helpful folks got a DBeaver install that you could try this on?

Comment: Sure enough V23.0.5 of DBeaver does give me a NULL too

Comment: Thank you for checking my sanity @RiggsFolly !!  much apprecitated. I guess I'll raise a ticket with DBeaver..... standby.